i need to restructure code for the addition of more equations with many similar use variables and keep the code succinct
I need to add 20 or so countries with part variable names like UK, US with multiple equations for each, each of which is structurally identical.
Some typical lines of code are shown ('model.add' etc is for the solver input and can be ignored):
#(-1) is not -1 it has meaning in the model solver of a reference to the previous period.
#UKUS has meaning 'from to'. Just think of the first two characters as the VAR of interest. RUK is of interest as UK.
#I am not asking how to rewrite the code, rather how to restructure it.
model.add('YDrUK = (YUK + RUK(-1)*BdUKUK(-1) + XRUS*RUS(-1)*BsUKUS(-1))*(1 - thetaUK) + d(XRUS)*BsUKUS(-1)')
model.add('YDhsUK = YDrUK + d(XRUS)*BsUKUS(-1)') # 12.2 : Haig-Simons disposable income in the UK
model.add('VUK - VUK(-1) = YDrUK - CONSUK')      # 12.3 : Wealth accumulation in the UK
# 12.4 : Disposable income in the US
model.add('YDrUS = (YUS + RUS(-1)*BdUSUS(-1) + XRUK*RUK(-1)*BsUSUK(-1))*(1 - thetaUS) + d(XRUK)*BsUSUK(-1)')
model.add('YDhsUS = YDrUS + d(XRUK)*BsUSUK(-1)') # 12.5 : Haig-Simons disposable income in the US
model.add('VUS - VUS(-1) = YDrUS - CONSUS')      # 12.6 : Wealth accumulation in the US
model.add('TUK = thetaUK*(YUK + RUK(-1)*BdUKUK(-1) + XRUS*RUS(-1)*BsUKUS(-1))')  # 12.7 : Taxes in the UK
model.add('TUS = thetaUS*(YUS + RUS(-1)*BdUSUS(-1) + XRUK*RUK(-1)*BsUSUK(-1))')  # 12.8 : Taxes in the US


model.add('FcbUK = RUK(-1)*BcbdUKUK(-1) + RUS(-1)*BcbsUKUS(-1)*XRUS')  # 12.11 : UK central bank profits
model.add('FcbUS = RUS(-1)*BcbdUSUS(-1)')        # 12.12 : US central bank profits
model.add('BsUK = BsUK(-1) + GUK + RUK(-1)*BsUK(-1) - TUK - FcbUK')  # 12.13 : UK Govt budget constraint
model.add('BsUS = BsUS(-1) + GUS + RUS(-1)*BsUS(-1) - TUS - FcbUS')  # 12.14 : US Govt budget constraint

NOTE the code is applied to a solver for which (-1) means the previous period
What i am looking for is something like [[i,j,k],[i,j,k]..] where i="a Uk variable/reference", j ="a US variable/reference" to a particular variable such as YDrUK, YDrUS in the  positions i,j  of [i,j,k]first cell and line "FcbUK=" is associated with a subsequent [i,,]., or better.
I thought i might be able to associate an index in an array to each variable but i don't know how to do that.
Alternatively, i thought that i could write one line to select a country name corresponding to an index for the purpose of charting and file output. That is show country name and its data on plots against say trade or GNP for each.
What i am looking for is ease of maintenance to add countries and change parameters, and minimal LOC overall.

You can write something like for c1, c2 in [('UK', 'US'), ('US', 'UK')]: model.add(f'YDhs{c1} = YDr{c1} + d(XR{c2})*Bs{c1}{c2}(-1)') and so on using f-strings.

Thanks for that.  I got a response from chatGPT, after several prompts, which is too long to fit in a comment.  What i was thinking was to map the data to XX and YY for any pair of countries for each of the variables, then do the solver, then map back.

I didn't know f strings could be used like that. It is late here, so i will look at that tomorrow in conjunction with my own thoughts on how to include more countries

If you agree, write this up as an answer and i will accept it. CHatGPT gave this when prompted...# Iterate over each country pair
for c1, c2 in country_pairs:
# Construct equations using f-strings
model.add(f'YDhs{c1} = YDr{c1} + d(XR{c2})*Bs{c1}{c2}(-1)')
model.add(f'V{c1} - V{c1}(-1) = YDr{c1} - CONS{c1}')
model.add(f'Fcb{c1} = R{c1}(-1)*Bcbd{c1}{c1}(-1) + R{c2}(-1)*Bcbs{c1}{c2}(-1)*XR{c2}')
model.add(f'Bs{c1} = Bs{c1}(-1) + G{c1} + R{c1}(-1)*Bs{c1}(-1) - T{c1} - Fcb{c1}')
# Add more equations as needed

You can write it in the following way using f-strings (I used print here instead of model.add):
from itertools import product

countries = ['UK', 'US', 'DE']


# Example for equation with one country:

for c in countries:
    print(f'V{c} - V{c}(-1) = YDr{c} - CONS{c}')


# Example for equation with two countries:

for c1, c2 in product(countries, repeat=2):
    if c1 == c2:
        continue

    print(f'YDhs{c1} = YDr{c1} + d(XR{c2})*Bs{c1}{c2}(-1)')

Output:
VUK - VUK(-1) = YDrUK - CONSUK
VUS - VUS(-1) = YDrUS - CONSUS
VDE - VDE(-1) = YDrDE - CONSDE
YDhsUK = YDrUK + d(XRUS)*BsUKUS(-1)
YDhsUK = YDrUK + d(XRDE)*BsUKDE(-1)
YDhsUS = YDrUS + d(XRUK)*BsUSUK(-1)
YDhsUS = YDrUS + d(XRDE)*BsUSDE(-1)
YDhsDE = YDrDE + d(XRUK)*BsDEUK(-1)
YDhsDE = YDrDE + d(XRUS)*BsDEUS(-1)

